# Get user Posts and/or Comments in a sharing blog using SQL

Tags: sql, android-activity, comments, blogs, posts

This (My)SQL problem will make me crazy if not solved this week-end!

A simple shared blog (means many authors contribute). Let's consider that two tables on my database:

**Posts**:

- id
- author_id
- title
- content

**Comments**:

- id
- author_id
- post_id
- content

**Goal: I want to display all the activities of a contributor (=> fixed author_id)**. What I mean by activity is:

- If the user created the post and commented: Display the post title and the user comment
- If the user created the post but doesn't comment: Display only post title
- If the user didn't create the post, but commented: Display the post title and the user comment

I tried this SQL Script:

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id, p.author_id AS post_author_id, c.author_id AS comment_author_id, title, c.content

FROM Posts p JOIN Comments c ON p.id = c.post_id

WHERE p.author_id = $userId

OR c.author_id = $userId
```

Looks fine, but it doesn't give me the row where the user created the post, but doesn't comment.

Any idea?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: You need different kind of JOIN - try `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Anyways, read more of differences between different joins http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: You saved my Week-end, scibuff! Thanks a lot. I'm using MySQL, so FULL OUTER JOIN isn't supported. But, LEFT OUTER JOIN works well. Add your comment as an answer, so I can validate it. Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL, you need to UNION the results of Posts outer joined to Comments, with those of Comments outer joined to Posts - like so:

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id, 
       p.author_id AS post_author_id, 
       c.author_id AS comment_author_id,
       p.title, 
       c.content
FROM Posts p 
LEFT JOIN Comments c ON p.id = c.post_id AND c.author_id = $userId
WHERE p.author_id = $userId
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id AS post_id, 
       p.author_id AS post_author_id, 
       c.author_id AS comment_author_id,
       p.title, 
       c.content
FROM Posts p 
RIGHT JOIN Comments c ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE c.author_id = $userId
```

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answer. It works great, and it's a nice example of how to emulate FULL JOIN. In my case, it'll not be necessary because a comment can't exists without a post, so the LEFT JOIN is sufficient. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hassinus - however, the user that you are interested in may have offered a comment on a post by *another* author - which is why you need the second select.

Comment: You're right! I was wrong because my testing has given me the rows I expected, but I didn't consider the situation you exposed. Now I have the ORDER activity problem (by most recent post or comment), here is the complete problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532140/how-to-select-the-max-of-two-element-of-each-row-in-mysql

Comment: Unfortunately, this SQL script gives the posts that were created by the $userId (this is OK) and also all the comments by other authors. If the $userId didn't comment, how to get only the post info (title, id,...) but no comments (set to null)? Am I clear?

Comment: @Hassinus: Yes - you include a condition in the first select's left join's ON clause to restrict the comment authors to $userId; I have updated the answer accordingly.