# How to select the max of two element of each row in MySQL

Tags: sql, timestamp, blogs, max

I have got a table that is a result of a (My)SQL query. In this table I have the post creation timestamp and the user comment creation timestamp. The trick is that not all posts have a comment (so some `comment_creation` are NULL).

I would like to order the rows according of the most recent creation time of the post or user comment.

How can I get the `max(post_creation, comment_creation)` of each row and order them (`DESC` order)?

Thanks for all contribution.

Comment: I assume `comment_creation` (if it exists) is always bigger than `post_creation`?

Comment: Indeed. But we have first to check if comment_creation exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous question, try:

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id, 
       p.author_id AS post_author_id, 
       p.created_date AS post_created,
       c.author_id AS comment_author_id,
       c.created_date AS comment_created,
       p.title, 
       c.content,
       coalesce(c.created_date,p.created_date) AS sort_date
FROM Posts p 
LEFT JOIN Comments c ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE p.author_id = $userId
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id AS post_id, 
       p.author_id AS post_author_id, 
       p.created_date AS post_created,
       c.author_id AS comment_author_id,
       c.created_date AS comment_created,
       p.title, 
       c.content,
       c.created_date AS sort_date
FROM Posts p 
RIGHT JOIN Comments c ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE c.author_id = $userId
ORDER BY sort_date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help Mark. Your code successfully works in my case. For those who want to undersatnd more, see my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530760/get-user-posts-and-or-comments-in-a-sharing-blog-using-sql

Comment: @Hassinus: Perhaps you are not aware that you are allowed (and greatly encouraged) to [formally accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") the answer that has helped you most with your problem, one answer per question. When you gain just a little bit more reputation on SO, you'll also be able to [upvote answers and questions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up "Vote up questions and answers").

Answer (score 0):

Given your table looks something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE `yourtable` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_creation` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_creation` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

...the `SELECT`-query could be done like this:

```
SELECT IF(comment_creation > post_creation, 
          comment_creation, 
          post_creation) AS sortorder,
       id
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY sortorder DESC;
```

Comment: Your answer seems interesting. But it concerns a comparison between two values: Max(A,B). What about more than two values: Max(A1,A2,...,An)? Is there any (My)SQL function?

Comment: Please provide more details how your table looks like. MAX() is an aggregate function and used to compare different rows, not different fields.

Comment: Let's consider a scholar class with N subjects (math, biology,...). Each row (in my database) is a student, and each column is a subject. Than, each field in my database contains the score of a student for a subject. How can I get which is the best score, and the corresponding subject, for each student?

Comment: That doesn't resemble the question very much. For this one, I'd use another database approach. Three tables: studends, classes, and a score table. Then you can use groups, joins, and much more to reach your desired goal.